# Expected unqualified-id at beginning bracket of function

Tags: c++, function, compiler-errors

I don't believe that I am missing any brackets or semi colons. Not sure what else the error could be for honestly. Any ideas?

Please excuse the messy notes ahead of time but anyways - I left a note where I am getting the expected unqualified-id error

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int binarySearch(const int [], int, int);

    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1000;            // Array size

    int main()
    {

        int accountNumbers[ARRAY_SIZE];         // Array with 1000 elements
        double accountBalances[ARRAY_SIZE];     // Array with 1000 elements
        int count = 0;                          // Input file stream object
        ifstream inputFile;
        ofstream outputFile;

        // Open the file.
        inputFile.open("FinalNumbers.txt");
        outputFile.open("Final_Random_Accounts_Sorted_Mazzei_Chris.txt");

        // Read the numbers from the file into the array
        while (count < ARRAY_SIZE && inputFile >> accountNumbers[count] >> accountBalances[count] ) {
            count++;
        }

        inputFile.close();

        int tempAccNumber = 0;
        int tempAccBalance = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE - 1 ; ++j)
            for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE - 1; ++i)
                if (accountNumbers[i] > accountNumbers [i + 1])
                {
                    tempAccNumber = accountNumbers[i];
                    accountNumbers[i] = accountNumbers[i +1];
                    accountNumbers[i + 1] = tempAccNumber;
                    tempAccBalance = accountBalances[i];
                    accountBalances[i] = accountBalances[i + 1];
                    accountBalances[i + 1] = tempAccBalance;
                }

        // Move assorted numbers to new file
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
            outputFile << accountNumbers[i] << endl;
            outputFile << accountBalances[i] << endl;
        }

        outputFile.close();
        cout << "done" << endl;

        int accNUM;
        int results;

        cout << "Enter an account number to be found: ";
        cin >> accNUM;

        results = binarySearch(accountNumbers, ARRAY_SIZE, accNUM);

        cout << "id is found at " << results;
    }

    int binarySearch(const int array[], int size, int value);
    // expected unqualified-id error with bracket below.
    {
        int first = 0,
            last = size - 1,
            middle,
            position = - 1;
        bool found = false;

        while (!found && first <= last) {
            middle = (first + last) / 2;
            if (array[middle] == value) {
                found = true;
                position = middle;
            }
            else if (array[middle] > value)
                last = middle - 1;
                else
                    first = middle + 1;

                    }

        return position;
    }
```

Comment: typo: remove the `;` end of this line: `int binarySearch(const int array[], int size, int value);`

Comment: @RichardCritten Ah missed that one, Thank you.

Comment: You'd probably have spotted that if you'd reduced your program to a [MCVE] before posting, as a semicolon is easier to spot in a three-line program than in an 86-line program (though the compiler did point you to precisely the trouble spot). That should be one of the very first steps you take in your debugging. Please do so next time.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I didn't reduce program because I didn't think of it so thank you I'll keep that in mind next time. My compiler pointed me to the line where bracket started so my search took place right under the actual line with error resulting in me looking right underneath the mistake the whole time.

Comment: @Chris if the problem is not obvious always look back a few lines.  As in this case, the compiler got a bit confused (by the semi-colon) and then gets really upset a line later when it can't continue parsing.  This is normal behaviour for most compilers.